# Do you use document ready in a PhoneGap application?

Tags: jquery, cordova

Is the jQuery method `$(document).ready(...)` a reliable way to start an application when using PhoneGap on a device?

Is this event triggered correctly when the app is started?

Comment: I dont know its reliable way or not. But i used it and its working fine..

Comment: It worked for me. you can use `deviceready` event. This is an event that fires when PhoneGap is fully loaded. for more info visit http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html